# light-locker error

Tags: lock-screen, light-locker

My session is not locking, either manually or when sleep or standby
xflock4 does nothing

dt1:light-locker-command -a

(light-locker-command:9191): GLib-CRITICAL **: the GVariant format string '(b)' has a type of '(b)' but the given value has a type of '(s)'

(light-locker-command:9191): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get: assertion 'valid_format_string (format_string, TRUE, value)' failed

xubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: I tried removing and re-installing light-locker

Comment: Progress.   I needed to run light-locker (command line).  Not sure how it got broken or if it will work after next reboot.   The error handling could really be improved.